# Getting websockets 404 Error on Rails 5 Deployment to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket, http-status-code-404

I'm deploying a simple Rails 5 app (https://morseaa.herokuapp.com/) to Heroku and cannot seem to get websockets to function correctly. The app works perfectly fine on local host, but whenever websockets functionality is invoked on the heroku deployment, I get the following error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://morseaa.herokuapp.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue? I have the same problem with java app...

Comment: I have the same issue with Rails 5 =\